# Ansible: Override group variables

Tags: variables, ansible

There are group changes - `group_vars/all.yml`

```yaml
software:
  test1:
    name: "vars1"
  test2:
    name: "vars2"
```

`group_vars/web.yml`

```yaml
software:
  test1:
    name: "vars_web"
```

`inventory`

```ini
[web]
server1
```

When you start a role, it takes variables from `group_vars/web.yaml`. It overrides the entire variable tree (`software`).

Is it possible to keep the tree and redefine only the specified variables?

```yaml
software:
  test1:
    name: "vars_web"
  test2:
    name: "vars2"
```

I don't know what to try ...

Answer (score 1):

> *It overrides the entire variable tree (`software`)*

Right, this is the expected behavior and caused by [variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence).

> *Is it possible to keep the tree and redefine only the specified variables?*

Yes, of course, but by organizing the structure and defining before [where to put a variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable). In any case in Ansible variables are not modified in place but redefined.

> *In general, Ansible gives precedence to variables that were defined more recently, more actively, and with more explicit scope.*

**General Documentation Links**

- [Understanding variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence)
- [Controlling how Ansible behaves: precedence rules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/general_precedence.html)

---

An other less preferable option might be to maintain two different trees of variables.

Also one could have a look into the [`update_fact` module – Update currently set facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/utils/update_fact_module.html).

Comment: I tried to play with priorities, the tree is redefined there, it will not be saved, but redefined by new variables

Comment: Since I don't understand the comment at all, can you update your initial question with new information if available and if necessary?